# A first course in Modular Forms: Ex 1.1.4

Tags: modular-forms

Question:

> Exercise 1.1.4(a)Let $k\geq 3$ be an integer and let $L' = \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Show that the series
> $$\sum_{(c,d) \in L'} (\sup\{|c|, |d|\})^{-k}$$ converges by considering the partial sums over expanding squares.

Can someone explain what does it mean by 'expanding squares'? Or any other hints to prove the convergence?

Source: [Diamond and Shurman's A First Course of Modular Forms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-27226-9).

Comment: For instance, the sum over the square with $-R\le c,d\le R$

Answer (score 0):

My attempt following the hints provided above:

Let $R >0$ (for convenience we set $R$ to be an integer) be given and by symmetry the partial sum
$$S_R := \sum_{\substack{- R \leq c \leq R\\ -R \leq d \leq R}} (\sup\{|c|, |d|\})^{-k}$$
can be written as $4$ times of the sum in the first quadrant, more specifically
$$S_R =4 S_1 := 4 \sum_{\substack{0 \leq c \leq R\\ 0 \leq d \leq R\\ c^2 + d^2 \ne0}} (\sup\{|c|, |d|\})^{-k}$$
By symmetry with respect to the line $y=x$ we have
$$S_1 := \sum_{n=1}^R \frac{1}{n^k} + 2 \sum_{0 \leq d \leq R} \sum_{d < c \leq R} \frac{1}{c^k}$$
where the double sum on the right can be evaluated as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{0 \leq d \leq R} \sum_{d < c \leq R} \frac{1}{c^k} &= \sum_{n=1}^R \frac{1}{n^k} + \sum_{n=2}^R \frac{1}{n^k} + \dots + \sum_{n=R-1}^R \frac{1}{n^k}\\
&= \frac{1}{1^k} + 2 \frac{1}{2^k} + \dots + R \frac{1}{R^k}\\
&= \frac{1}{1^{k-1}} + \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} + \dots + \frac{1}{R^{k-1}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^R \frac{1}{n^{k-1}}
\end{align*}
Thus, the initial partial sum is bounded above by
$$4\left(\sum_{n=1}^R \frac{1}{n^k} + 2\sum_{n=1}^R \frac{1}{n^{k-1}} \right)$$ which is certainly bounded as $R$ tends to infinity since $k \geq 3$.

Do let me know if there are any gaps in the proof.